# How to use DSC to differentiate first and second order phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, liquid-crystals, differential-scanning-calorimetry

The DSC trace below was recorded for a thermotropic calamitic liquid crystal. The heating rate was 5 $^\text{o}$C min$^{-1}$; a heating scan is followed by a cooling scan.

[image]

Based on the previously reported result, there are two phase transitions to be expected in the temperature range of interest: from crystal to a nematic phase, then to an isotropic phase.

From the DSC trace, how can we say something about the [order of the phase transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition#Ehrenfest_classification)?

**1.** The most popular answer from [this site](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_distinguish_the_1st_and_2nd_order_phase_transitions_from_DSC_analysis) says:

> If you want to see whether your transitions are first or second order,
> you must run modulated DSC, where the non-reversing and reversing part
> of the heat flow is related to the first and second-order transitions,
> respectively.

What is the reason for first-order phase transition being non-reversing while second-order being reversing?

**2.** Second-order phase transition $\implies \Delta S = 0 \implies \Delta H = 0$ at transition temperature. Based on this, shouldn't any second-order phase transition not shown in the DSC trace (because no heat exchanged at constant pressure during that transition)?